# iOS 8; open native app from javascript

Tags: javascript, ios8, mobile-safari

In Safari on iOS 7 this code works (have used it for the past two years):

```
setTimeout("document.location = 'MyAppName://type=a&id=123';",10);
```

But it dosn't work in Safari iOS 8 and I can't seem to find any clues anywhere. Does somebody have a clue?

Comment: I think they tried to patch that in iOS8 because users were annoyed that a website would try to open an app

Comment: Sounds very possible.

Answer (score 0):

i found not very good, but solution.

try to replace '=' by '?'

like that:

```
setTimeout("document.location = 'MyAppName://type?a&id?123';",10);
```

and i finally find better solution without replace.

just make this sting  like url whith domain.

```
setTimeout("document.location = 'MyAppName://domain.com/type=a&id=123';",10);
```

Comment: This actually opens the app (?!) - however the app can't detect the url parameters and just opens instead of getting the user to the right destination.

Comment: In my case it works. Safari in IOS8 cant work with symbols '=' and ':' in url when you use document.location

Comment: So instead of document.location what should I use? Do you know where apple has this change documented?